# Moving an Angular Component into DOM

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to move into DOM an Angular Component, with it's current state after user action.

This specific need is born because I have a central search bar (position absolute) out of my HTML structure. And when user select an item out of propositions when typing, I want the search bar to decrease it's size and be placed into one of my HTML column (and change position to relative).

I've not seen something to do this that isn't deprecated.(ComponentResolver deprecated and no docs).

In my component.ts file I get the reference of the elements by doing this :

```
@ViewChild("searchInput") searchInput: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('searchContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) searchContainer;
```

And in my html template :

```
<nv-page>
    <!-- here search component in absolute position, centered by default in page -->
   <search-cmp #searchInput></search-cmp>
   <nv-board>
      <div class="row">
         <div #searchContainer class="col-md-6">  
             <!-- place search bar HERE when item selected -->
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
      </div>
   </nv-board>
</nv-page>
```

Is it something that I can do properly ? Is there another way ?
thanks a lot

Comment: you can move a component between view containers, but the the component has to be created dynamically to do so. Is it feasible for you case? You can read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) and [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) for some background

Comment: `ngTemplateOutlet` can help you

Comment: @Maximus I tried the tutorial on hackernoon, it works well, but I've noticed that I can't pass @Input or @Output to a dynamically created component :( I didn't wrote it down in my example because I didn't want to overload the markup, but I have something like `<search-cmp #searchInput [param]="myinput" (onItemSelected)="itemSelected($event)" ></search-cmp>`

Comment: And @yurzui ngTemplateOutlet is more like something to pass args to a templateView but I'll dig a bit more on this

Comment: @Alex, yeah, that's the limitation and neither `ngTemplateOutlet ` nor `ngComponentOutlet` doesn't solve that problem

Comment: Can you add runnable repro?

Comment: @Maximus I managed to access Inputs and EventEmitters via the 'instance' object of the ComponentRef containing my dynamically instanciated component.

Comment: @Alex, yeah, that's possible. You can't make Angular process them automatically however

Comment: @Maximus exactly, that's why I had to listen to an attribute of my parent component, and each time it change, apply the new value for the input. Anyway, thanks for the hint !

Comment: @yurzui thank you also for your reply, however, I admit I'm not a fan of running examples for such small questions. I think it's kind of overkill to deploy a fully fonctionnal example, extracted from my real app for a 'theorical' question.